# how to stop the textformfield being submit to mysql when the validator still not correct using flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter

I have inserted the value that not valid but the system still allows save it on MySQL. how to prevent it from submit?

textfieldform

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:30,right:30,top:0,bottom:0 ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      autocorrect: true,
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (input)=> input.isValidPass() ? null: "         must contain of 8 value with at least 1 uppercase & 1 \nlowercase & 1 number & 1 character!",
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Userss1!',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

password extension

```
extension PassValidator on String {
  bool isValidPass() {
    return RegExp(
        r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: "the system still allows save it on MySQL" then maybe it is a good idea to show those lines, too. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not touch anything on the code above, but on the

onPressed:/onClick, I did adding some rules before the process can be run. must contain value of at least 1 uppercase & 1 \nlowercase & 1 number & 1 character. The Flutter code below is located in the IF statement inside RaisedButton. The condition must meet first to ensure the next condition executable, else it will popup a dialog message.

Flutter code: (the condition mean if the password [does not(!)] contain RegEXP)

```
else if(!passwordController.text.contains(RegExp(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$'))){
                    showDialog(
                        context:context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Please enter the valid password!"),
                          );
                        });
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the information you have provided and my understanding, for this you need to wrap it around form builder widget from [FormBuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder)

```
GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> formbuilderkey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

FormBuilder(
key: formbuilderkey,
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:30,right:30,top:0,bottom:0 ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      autocorrect: true,
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (input)=> input.isValidPass() ? null: "         must contain of 8 value with at least 1 uppercase & 1 \nlowercase & 1 number & 1 character!",
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Userss1!',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),),
```

and onClick of save button you can do some thing like this.

```
    if(formbuilderkey.currentState.saveAndValidate()){
 
...}
```